# wrap inherited classes in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, wrapper

Let's say I have a number of inherited classes

```py
class Bird:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def identify(self):
        print("I am a generic bird!")
        
class Falcon(Bird):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Eagle, self).__init__()
    def identify(self):
        print("I am a Falcon!")

class Eagle(Bird):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Eagle, self).__init__()
    def identify(self):
        print("I am an Eagle!")
```

This allows me to create, e.g., a Falcon using

```py
A = Falcon()
A.identify
```

```
I am a Falcon
```

What I would like to have now is something like a wrapper class, which allows me to choose the kind of bird using a flag. Specifically, I want this behavior

```py
A = BirdSelector(which="Falcon")
A.identify
B = BirdSelector(which="Eagle")
B.identify
```

```
I am a Falcon!
I am a Eagle!
```

In short, `A = BirdSelector(which="Eagle")` is supposed to create an instance of `Falcons` just as if I had called `A = Falcon()`. What is the most pythonic way to do this? Can someone give a hint how to implement `BirdSelector`?

Comment: It's basically just a *factory function.* `return {'Falcon': Falcon, ...}[which]()`

Comment: [Factory pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factory-method-python-design-patterns/)